# restrict Slack access outside work network?

Tags: slack

If an organization would like to make slack accessible only via the work internet and block its usage when logged in from home, is that possible? We are doing a trial run to see if it would fit our needs and one of the requirements is to not allow Slack to be accessible outside of the work network.

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a customer service question related to a third-party product that should be addressed to that third party directly. It is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.